# React JS, logical error in Redux state updation

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My Todo code accepts new todo from users and update the Redux store. There seems to be a problem with my reducer function

```
const initialState = {
    tasks: ['notodo'],
    completedTasks: ['nothing']
}

const todoState = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
     case 'ADDTODO':
        return { 
          ...state,
          tasks: [...tasks, action.payload]
        };
     default:
       return state;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? How does `action.payload` look like?

Comment: action.payload = 'string value'

Comment: tasks in not defined in your `'ADDTODO'` case. I am guessing it should be : `tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload]`

Comment: and could you show the way you call the action ?

Comment: const addtodo=(todo)=>{
    return{
        type:'ADDTODO',
        payload:todo
    }
}


export default addtodo

Comment: it should be tasks: [...state.tasks, action.payload],as you said, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case 'ADDTODO':
    return { 
      ...state,
      tasks: [...tasks, action.payload] // Here ...tasks is undefined
    };

 It should be [...state.tasks, action.payload]
```